# Does magic whistling a pet out of a trap count as untrapping?

Tags: nethack

More curiosity than strategy.  I know untrapping a pet gives an alignment boost if you #untrap.  But, does using a magic whistle give the same alignment boost?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Using a magic whistle simply removes a pet from a trap, without any of the additional effects that untrapping has.  From the source code, `use_magic_whistle()` in `apply.c`:

```
if (mtmp->mtame) {
    if (mtmp->mtrapped) {
        /* no longer in previous trap (affects mintrap) */
        mtmp->mtrapped = 0;
        fill_pit(mtmp->mx, mtmp->my);
    }
```

(`fill_pit()` deals with the possibility that teleporting your pet resulted in a boulder being left on top of a pit trap.)